# Exercises for Apex programming

Tags: apex

Recently I started learning Apex programming.  I was trying to get some examples, but I could not find enough to practice my code.  Please provide me links or exercises so that I could practice concepts like class, objects, soql, dml etc.

Comment: If you can suggest a workbook with full of exercises, that is also fine

Comment: Salesforce provides [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home) for this purpose. It includes both instruction and projects to complete.

Answer (score -1):

Trailhead is the best to learn the Salesforce for beginner

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home